# How does the "Add new user" page loads

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I'm trying to figure out how Orchard "Add user" page is loaded. I have a little knowledge of MVC. These are the parts that load into the page:

**Add user main page:**

..\Orchard.Web\Modules\Orchard.Users\Views\Admin\Create.cshtml

**Create user part:** 
..\Orchard.Web\Modules\Orchard.Users\Views\EditorTemplates\Parts\User.Create.cshtml

**Roles part:**
..\Orchard.Web\Modules\Orchard.Roles\Views\EditorTemplates\Parts\Roles.UserRoles.cshtml

**Save button:**
..\Orchard.Web\Core\Contents\Views\Content.SaveButton.cshtml

My question is how are these separate parts become joined in a single page? Which class is responsible for doing that?

[image]

Comment: your code is responsible for that.

Comment: The reason i'm asking this question is because i'm working on Coevery CRM that is based on Orchard. However, for Coevery, the Save button is not shown although the same parts exist in the code. So i'm trying to figure out how the page parts are loaded to know why the Save button doesn't load.

Comment: its difficult to say without looking into your code. There might be some conditions inside the page to toggle the rendering of some pages .

Comment: Yes, I understand but the code is too big. I thought someone might already have used Orchard who is familiar with the code and can help me with. This is the OOB Orchard pages and code with no customizations. Thank you for your reply though

Comment: oh I get your point now, Hope so somebody comes for help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These separate parts are conjoined by the responsible **Drivers** of the parts. These drivers are responsible for rendering the shapes that come with that part. For example, the SaveButton is rendered in the ContentsDriver in Orchard.Core/Contents/Drivers/ContentsDriver:

```
protected override DriverResult Editor(ContentPart part, dynamic shapeHelper) {
    var results = new List<DriverResult> { ContentShape("Content_SaveButton", saveButton => saveButton) };

    if (part.TypeDefinition.Settings.GetModel<ContentTypeSettings>().Draftable)
        results.Add(ContentShape("Content_PublishButton", publishButton => publishButton));

    return Combined(results.ToArray());
}
```

Although the drivers are responsible for the rendering of the shapes, the regulation of the kickin off of the drivers is done through placement.info (see Orchard.Core/Contents/Placement.info):

```
<Placement>
    <Place Content_SaveButton="Sidebar:23"/>
</Placement>
```

If somewhere (in a module or a theme) is defined that the savebutton should not be displayed, it will probably be done through placement.info. You'll probably need to search for somewhere where it says something like this:

```
<Placement>
    <!-- This will cause the savebutton not to render -->
    <Place Content_SaveButton="-"/>
</Placement>
```

Or, because it says it should render the save button in the SideBar zone, it might be that some alternate that is used does not display the SideBar zone (`@Display(Model.SideBar)`)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I debugged Coevery and it turned out as you said that the @Display(Model.SideBar) is not loaded. This line is in a .cshtml class Content-user.Edit.cshtml, it is rendered in Orchard but not in Coevery. Now i guess my next step will be finding out why this template doesn't get rendered.